# Removing Object from JSONArray

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have an application that gets an api key and account name from a webservice, I am storing this apikey and account name for further use(multiple accounts and apikeys).

because you can only store primitive types in the sharedPreferences I parse the JSONArray toString.
In another part of the application the user must be able to remove an account from his app.
So I retrieve the string and Parse it back to an JSONArray.

how do I remove an JSONObject from the array and save it so I can parse it back to an string and save it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should convert it in arraylist and remove object and create jsonarray,,,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//First Position remove
list.remove(0);
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

Comment: min SDK  for remove() method is 19

Answer (score 3):

i use:

```
public static JSONArray RemoveJSONArray( JSONArray jarray,int pos) {

JSONArray Njarray=new JSONArray();
try{
for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){     
    if(i!=pos)
        Njarray.put(jarray.get(i));     
}
}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
return Njarray;

}
```